# How to sum count in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

When i used this to count how many employees working in each departments , its working fine :

```
-- Count
    totals.Nr_Employees as TotalEmployees

    LEFT JOIN
        (select p1.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
        from Paychecks p1
        join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
        where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
        group by p1.DepartmentName 
        )  totals on totals.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
```

BUT, when i want to make total of count or sum count , i do something like this ,but its not working and i dont know its right way to do or not ! Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
-- SUM
    SummerCount.TotalEmployees as sumEmployees
    LEFT JOIN
        (select p1.DepartmentName, sum(count(distinct u.Id)) TotalEmployees
        from Paychecks p1
        join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
        where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
        group by p1.DepartmentName
        ) SummerCount on SummerCount.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
```

AND , put Querys together:

```
-- Count & SUM
    totals.Nr_Employees as TotalEmployees,
    SummerCount.TotalEmployees as sumEmployees

    FROM

    LEFT JOIN
        (select p1.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
        from Paychecks p1
        join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
        where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
        group by p1.DepartmentName 
        )  totals on totals.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName

    LEFT JOIN
        (select p1.DepartmentName, sum(count(distinct u.Id)) TotalEmployees
        from Paychecks p1
        join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
        where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
        group by p1.DepartmentName
        ) SummerCount on SummerCount.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
```

**Screenshots (wrong sum)**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a common table expression to get replace the first query, and select sum from that cte to replace the second one:

```
;WITH EmployeesCount AS
(
    select p1.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
    from Paychecks p1
    join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
    where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
    group by p1.DepartmentName 
)
```

And then, in your main query:

```
...
LEFT JOIN
EmployeesCount As totals on totals.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(Nr_Employees) 
    FROM EmployeesCount
) As SummerCount on SummerCount.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
```

### Update

```
;WITH EmployeesCount AS
(
    select p1.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
    from Paychecks p1
    join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
    where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
    group by p1.DepartmentName 
)

SELECT  totals.Nr_Employees as TotalEmployees,
        SummerCount.Nr_Employees as sumEmployees
FROM 
dbo.Paychecks AS p INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS u ON u.Id=p.UserId 
INNER JOIN dbo.EmploymentStatuses AS E ON E.Id = u.EmploymentStatusId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTerminationQueue AS etq on etq.UserId = u.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TerminationReasons AS t on t.Id = etq.TerminationReasonid    
LEFT JOIN EmployeesCount As totals on totals.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(Nr_Employees) As Nr_Employees
    FROM EmployeesCount
) As SummerCount
```

### Full query

```
;WITH EmployeesCount AS
(
    select p1.DepartmentName, count(distinct u.Id) Nr_Employees
    from Paychecks p1
    join Users u on u.Id = p1.UserId
    where u.customerid=214 and u.isdeleted=0
    group by p1.DepartmentName 
)


SELECT DISTINCT u.Id, u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName AS Medarbajder,
u.SSN AS CPRNR,
(CASE 
WHEN u.SSN IS NOT NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(YEAR,CONVERT(date,STUFF(LEFT(u.SSN, 4), 3, 0, '.') + '.' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) / 100 - 1 as char(2)) + SUBSTRING(u.SSN, 5, 2), 104) , GETDATE()) 
ELSE
NULL
END) As Aldre ,

 (CASE WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('1', '3', '5', '7', '9') THEN 'M'
             WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('2', '4', '6', '8', '0') THEN 'K'
        END) as Køn,

convert(varchar(10), p.WorkStartDate, 105) AS StartDato ,

(CASE
WHEN u.ResignationDate IS NOT NULL THEN

CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(dd, WorkStartDate, u.ResignationDate)/365) + ' år '+

CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(MONTH, WorkStartDate, u.ResignationDate) % 12) + ' måneder '+

CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, u.ResignationDate), WorkStartDate), u.ResignationDate), 
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, u.ResignationDate), WorkStartDate)), u.ResignationDate) AS varchar(2)) +' dag ' 

ELSE
CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(dd, WorkStartDate, GETDATE())/365) + ' år '+

CONVERT(varchar(4), DATEDIFF(MONTH, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()) % 12) + ' måneder '+

CAST(DATEDIFF(dd, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate), GETDATE()), 
DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, WorkStartDate, GETDATE()), WorkStartDate)), GETDATE()) AS varchar(2)) +' dag ' end) as Ancinitet,

(CASE
WHEN u.ResignationDate IS NOT NULL THEN
DATEDIFF(day, WorkStartDate, u.ResignationDate) 
ELSE
DATEDIFF(day, WorkStartDate, GETDATE())
end) as AncinitetAntalDag,

p.DepartmentName AS Afdelinger,

E.Name AS Ansættelsesstatus,
u.ResignationDate AS Opsigelsesdato,
(CASE WHEN etq.Id IS NOT NULL THEN t.Name ELSE 'Aktiv' END) AS Terminationreason,

totals.Nr_Employees as TotalEmployees,
SummerCount.Nr_Employees as sumEmployees

FROM 
 dbo.Paychecks AS p INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS u ON u.Id=p.UserId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.EmploymentStatuses AS E ON E.Id = u.EmploymentStatusId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.EmployeeTerminationQueue AS etq on etq.UserId = u.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TerminationReasons AS t on t.Id = etq.TerminationReasonid
LEFT JOIN EmployeesCount As totals on totals.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(Nr_Employees) As Nr_Employees
    FROM EmployeesCount
) As SummerCount 





 WHERE u.CustomerId=214 AND u.IsDeleted = 0 
AND etq.StartDate >= @EndDateFrom AND etq.StartDate <= @EndDateTo
AND 
((@Gender != 'B' AND
    @Gender =  (CASE WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('1', '3', '5', '7', '9') THEN 'M'
            WHEN right(rtrim(SSN), 1) IN ('2', '4', '6', '8', '0') THEN 'K'
            END))
OR
(@Gender = 'B'))
AND
((@TerminationReason != 0 AND @TerminationReason = (CASE WHEN etq.Id IS NOT NULL THEN t.Id ELSE 0 END))
OR
(@TerminationReason = 0))
AND u.EmploymentStatusId = 2
order by p.DepartmentName
```

Comment: tnx for your commnet , but i get little bit confused would you please put them together

Comment: I did. The cte (the part that starts in `;with` and ends in `)`) comes before your main query. Then you can use that in your query as if it was another table.

Comment: i just update my post ,under Updated Query ,i put them together,but its give me error

Comment: The cte is not a part of the main query - it should be before it. The structure is something like this: `;With cte as (<select statement>) select <columns> from cte`

Comment: i was update my question with ,one part which called 'Updated Query' ,i dont know if you see or not , i did as you said but give me error or i did something wrong in structure

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please check the code after **Update**

Comment: i just past the code you wrote in my main query , i got error , i dont know why - i update my query to my main query , please check my question - under **'updated query'** again.

Comment: Edited my answer with the full query. Please try.

Comment: it give me error again .. i just update my question with a part **Screenshot of errors** please check the question again

Comment: I've edited my answer again. There was a `select` inside the main query that should probably not be there.

Comment: yeah , it was select but , now - i get another error - Invalid column name  (Nr_Employees) | SummerCount.Nr_Employees as sumEmployees LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(Nr_Employees) 
    FROM EmployeesCount
) As SummerCount on SummerCount.DepartmentName = p.DepartmentName

Comment: i also update the question with new screenshots , please check again under **Screenshot of errors**

Comment: Missing an alias on the `select sum(Nr_Employees)`... Fixed my answer.

Comment: alias was there before,anyways i got same error again

Comment: Edited once again, changed the left join to a cross join.

Comment: its works but , it give me a wrong sum , please chack again under **Screenshots** in my question

Comment: It gives the sum of the counts. That's what you asked for. Obviously I can't check it since I don't have the tables or the data you have. I don't think I can help more then I already did.

Comment: yeah , it gives the sum of the counts , but i didnt understand why like this as you see in screenshots (wrong sum) . i dont know where problem is ! anyway thank you so much for your help n time brother

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate functions as operators of aggregate functions are not supported. This is, why your statment doe not work.

You can either use the WITH ROLLUP clause or put your statement into a subselect and build the sums in the outer statement.

Comment: understood , would give me a example

Comment: By the way, is this really, what you want to be doing? When you sum up the counts of subgroups, you simply count the total.